# SAS Data Integration issue with empty string showing as "NULL"

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I am having an issue with SAS DI.
In certain columns, I would like the empty strings to appear as empty, instead of them being displayed as "NULL".
While they some times appear as empty, once I later run them in SQL, they come up as "NULL". I have attempted to use NUMCHAR variable in SAS DI, but I am not quite sure how to implement it as I am new to this language.

---

EDIT:

I will try to be more specific. In short, I have a workflow (Job) in SAS DI, where I have a table, I am using the table loader to choose some of the variables (i.e. A, B and C). The aforementioned variables have both values and empty values. On the occasion where an empty value appears, the table entry of that value is saved, although when I load it it shows as "NULL". What I would like to do, is change the workflow (either visually or using a code) to tell SAS DI to show values of columns A and B (but not C) as only empty (rather than "NULL")

Comment: Are you somehow asking to distinguish between a string that has only blanks in it and a missing (aka null) value?  SAS does not make any such distinction in SAS datasets.  Or are you seeing that the literal string `'NULL'` is being placed into your character variable somehow?  If you need to distinguish a difference between a `null` value and one that is either all blanks or of length zero then you will need to store that information in a separate field.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need a lot more information here to get a useful answer; in particular, you should add what steps you're using, what input data source, and what you're using to see the values (are you opening the dataset and browsing it, are you putting it in another RDBMS and then see it there, etc.).

Comment: I will try to be more specific. In short, I have a workflow (Job) in SAS DI, where I have a table, I am using the table loader to choose some of the variables (i.e. A, B and C). The aforementioned variables have both values and empty values. On the occasion where an empty value appears, the table entry of that value is saved, although when I load it it shows as "NULL". What I would like to do, is change the workflow (either visually or using a code) to tell SAS DI to show values of columns A and B (but not C) as only empty (rather than "NULL")